# Is it feasible to replace objects referenced by a list of references

Tags: c#, reference

Here's something I want to do in C#:

```
MyClass A, B, C;

void test(List<object> lst_ref)
{
   // assign each reference in lst_ref a new object
}
```

What I want to do is by calling

```
test(new list<object> {A, B, C})
```

to change not properties on objects referenced by A, B, C, but objects themselves pointed to by names A, B, C

I understand why above pseudo-code doesn't work

But I want to confirm what I wanted to do is not feasible in C#

(sorry I couldn't come up with a better title)

Comment: It sounds like you wish to replicate the behavior of `ref` on a single parameter, but with a list that contains the references to update?

Comment: exactly, sorry for my poor description

Comment: @huirong I had misunderstood your question. I don't think there is a way to do that other than going into `unsafe` territory and handling pointers.

Comment: No, you can't do that. You can put A, B, and C into the list, but if you want A, B, and C to change after the method, you'll need to assign each after the method is complete. I have a hunch a list isn't what you'd really want, either, but that's going to be up to your actual problem.

Comment: @Vache, thx for confirming

Comment: @Anthony, thx for confirming - with many objects of same class, each having its own name, I want find a cleaner syntax of manipulating them. anyway, I will go with whatever is available in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define a method that can assign a value to each of three different *variables* then yes, there are ways that you can do that, for example by using delegates:

```
public static void Set3Variables<T>(params Action<T>[] actions)
    where T : new()
{
    foreach (var action in actions)
        action(new T());
}
```

This would allow you to write:

```
Set3Variables<MyClass>(
    value => A = value,
    value => B = value,
    value => C = value);
```

And now after having called this method you'll have actually set those three variables, not just mutated the value of that variable or created some new values without affecting those three variables.

Comment: very interesting, never used this, let me play with it, thank u very much!